# Firefox NoScript ABE not working as expected

Tags: firefox, noscript

I use NoScript and ABE and most of the time I am successful and happy with it. I thought I understand the way it works (at least the basics). But for some websites, it just does NOT work the way I expect it to do.

For example: There is this map [here](http://www.opencaching.de/map2.php) on opencaching.de. It needs the following scripts:

```
opencaching.de
maps.googleapis.com
mts1.googleapis.com
```

If I whitelist them all in NoScript, the map shows. When I switch on ABE, it does not work.

I tried:

1. use ABE with no USER rules specified at all: works
2. use ABE with just a single rule like this: does not work

   ```
   Site maps.googleapis.com mts1.googleapis.com
   Accept from opencaching.de
   Deny
   ```

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

if you go [here](https://maps.googleapis.com/) and [here](http://mts1.googleapis.com/), you can clearly see they return **404 errors**! Adding *www.* in front fixes this and returns to google.com

According to the [ABE rules pdf](https://noscript.net/abe/abe_rules.pdf), in their examples they seem to either add a *.* or a **.* in front of their URLs

I think

```
Site .maps.googleapis.com .mts1.googleapis.com
Accept from .opencaching.de
Deny
```

Or maybe even

```
Site .googleapis.com
Accept from .opencaching.de
Deny
```

Might work! You could also try *.